# Cant remove certificate from store with Powershell

Tags: powershell, certificate, access-denied

I am trying to remove specific certificates (certificates for SAP):

```
$store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store “Root”,”LocalMachine”
$store.Open(“ReadWrite”)

foreach ($Curr in $store.Certificates)
{
    if ($Curr -like $serchPatern)
    {
        $store.Remove($curr)
    }
}
```

It gives this error:

> access denied

I tried the same thing with for loop (instead of `foreach`) it didn't work...

When I try to delete them without the script there is no problem.

When I try to remove other certificates with script there is no problem too... so the problem is with those specific certificates.

Anyone know what is the problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

Your session is probably not elevated. Right click the PowerShell icon and chose "Run as Administrator".

Comment: Still getting access denied?

Comment: Do you get the error when you execute the Open method? Verify that you have the correct privileges to open the store.

Comment: no, i get the error on the remove method, and it is only on specific certificates other certificates dont give me error

Comment: Can you remove them with MMC?